# Extrair apenas extensões específicas de um ZIP

Tags: php, laravel, arquivo-zip

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde em alguma parte dele o cliente poderá enviar um arquivo  `ZIP` contendo apenas imagens.

Eu estou querendo fazer de uma maneira que eu possa desse extrair desse `ZIP` apenas os arquivo que contenha extensões específica de imagem.

Eu sei que no PHP, quando vamos listar apenas um tipo de extensão existente num diretório, utilizamos a função `glob` para fazer isso.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma operação semelhante com a classe `ZipArchive` do PHP?

Se alguém conhecer algum plugin no `Laravel` que faça algo do tipo, será de muita utilidade tal informação.

**Nota**: O método ZipArchive::extractTo() aceita um segundo parâmetro, que é array de arquivos da `white list` dos arquivos que serão extraídos.

Seria bom isso também funcionasse com um `glob brace`!

Comment: Não é mais fácil extrair tudo e aproveitar só o que for imagem? O resto você pode excluir ao longo da sua rotina.

Comment: Pensei na mesma coisa, @RodrigoRigotti. Enquanto a resposta não chega, vou o usar o `FileSystemIterator` para isso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a biblioteca [Extractor](https://github.com/mmoreram/extractor), que extrai os arquivos comprimidos e retorna um objeto `Finder` do pacote `Symfony\Component`, documentação [aqui](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html).

Veja o exemplo para sua situação:

```
$temporaryDirectory = new Mmoreram\Extractor\Filesystem\TemporaryDirectory();
$extensionResolver = new Mmoreram\Extractor\Resolver\ExtensionResolver;
$extractor = new Mmoreram\Extractor\Extractor($temporaryDirectory, $extensionResolver);

$finder = $extractor->extractFromFile($uploadFile);

$validMimes = ["image/png", "image/jpg"];

$filter = function(\SplFileInfo $path) {
    $file = new File($path);

    if (in_array($file->getMimeType(), $validMimes)) {
        return true;
    }
};

$validFiles = $finder->files()->filter($filter);
```

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sim! Muito Obrigado

Comment: Assim que terminar de testar, se der tudo ok, marco como resolvido :)

Comment: Muito boa essa biblioteca. Pra utilizar ela, tem que ter o `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` instalado. E na hora de validar em `$filter`, tem que ter um `return false` para casos de não cair na validação de mimes. Muito obrigado, amigo!

Answer (score 0):

Baseando-me no conselho dado por @RodigoRigotti, elaborei o um código para exclusão dos arquivos de extensão indesejáveis. A extração é feita para uma pasta segura, para não dar acesso ao direto à pasta ao usuário (evitando assim um PHP injection).

```
 public function postAjaxUploadZip($id) {   
        $file = Input::file('zip');

        $rules = [
            'zip' => 'required|mimes:zip'
        ];

        $messages = [
            'mimes' => "Extensão de arquivo inválida"
        ];

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);


        if ($validation->passes()) {

            try{

                $zip = $file->getRealPath();

                $zipObject =  new ZipArchive;
                if (! $zipObject->open($zip)) {

                    throw new RunTimeException('Não foi possível abrir o arquivo enviado');
                }

                $path = base_path("secure/{$id}");  

                if (! File::isDirectory($path)) {

                    File::makeDirectory($path, 0755);
                }

                // Extrai para uma pasta segura, para o usuário não ter acesso a esses arquivos pelo pasta "public" do Laravel
                $zipObject->extractTo($path);

                // Itera com os arquivos do diretório onde houve a extração

                $files = new FileSystemIterator($path);

                foreach ($files as $file) {

                   $data = [
                      'file' => $file->getRealPath()
                   ];

                   $rules = ['file' => 'mimes:jpg,png,bmp,jpeg'];

                   if (Validator::make($data, $rules)->fails()) {

                      $deletedFiles[] = $file->getFilename();

                   }

                }   

                File::delete($filesToDelete);


            } catch (Exception $e) {

                return Response::json([
                    'error'     => $e->getMessage(),
                    'directory' => $path,
                ]);
            }


            return Response::json([
                'error' => false, 
                'deletedFiles' => $filesToDelete
            ]);

        } else {

            return Response::json(['error' => $validation->messages()]);    
        }
    }
```

Se alguém tiver uma ideia melhor, será de grande ajuda.
Quanto menos código melhor!

Comment: Não acho uma boa ideia a verificação da extensão por regex, pois a extensão do arquivo pode ser manipulada. Tente determinar se o arquivo realmente é uma imagem pelo mime-type, usando [`exif-imagetype`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) ou [`fileinfo`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

Comment: Eu posso então usar o `Validator` do `Laravel` para cada iteração, não é? Ele internamente usa o `FileInfo`

Comment: Boa ideia ! :) http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-mimes

Comment: Atualizei o código com a versão da Validação do `Laravel`!

Comment: Muito bom, @gmsantos. Quando estava fazendo os testes aqui, ele estava aceitando um `teste.jpg` que eu criei sendo que ele era um `txt` que eu tinha convertido (por preguiça) para testar o envio de arquivos no ZIP :)

Comment: Poderia ser um código malicioso esse arquivo (Um .php disfarçado de imagem)

Comment: Na verdade, não posso usar o mime do Validator, pois ele checa se é um upload também. Fiz mais uma alteração no código fonte!